# How to build Model Class dynamically with JSON file in angular 5

Tags: typescript, angular5

by reading json file, storing all names in one array and types in one array in a typescript class but how to build model class dynamically

Here is JSON

```
     "layoutItems": [ {

                                "type": "string",
                                "name": "firstname",
                                "label": "Name",
                                },
                            {
                                  "type": "string",
                                "name": "middlename",
                                "label": "Middle Name",
                                 },
                            {

                                "type": "number",
                                "name": "age",
                                "label": "Age",
                             },
                            {
                                "type": "number",
                                "name": "mobile",
                                "label": "Mobile",
                               },
    }]

need to build model export class like


  export class User{
        firstname: string;
        middlename: string;
        age: number;
        mobile: number;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to create a class at runtime time? Woulnd't you need an object? Or you want to create a class, and then be able to make instances of such a class?

Comment: building forms with JSON and able to create a record from forms using formcontrol but when i am trying to edit and display records in table format needed model class

Comment: Well, you could create a constructor at runtime, though it wouldn't be a TypeScript class, as during execution, there's only JavaScript and no types. So if you need such a class during compile time, you need to create it beforehand. Maybe you should give more details of why you need this (code examples and such)